# Volume Up/down press event in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, expo

I am using expo, and creating a music player app.
I wanted to implement controls to music player such that users can change songs with double pressing volume buttons, but I just cannot find how to do so.

**I just want a way to detect that volume button was pressed once or twice, thank you**